# Using an Oracle sequence when the data isn't a complete sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

Given a DB table containing a unique sequence as primary key, and an additional value VAL;

[image]

I need to retrieve the values that match 'like %b', but I need to retrieve them one at a time in a sequence. If the values were consecutive, I would just use an Oracle sequence to work through PKEY using nextval, currval etc.

The problem here is that if the sequence is 4, and I go for nextval, it gives me an incorrect value (a %a value instead of a %b value).

The one solution I can think of is to use the sequence with 'more than' rather than 'equals', so for example (excuse the pseudocode, I can work out correct syntax later);

```
select pkey, val from table where val like '%b' and pkey>seq.currval
```

And then shift the sequence past the value of pkey (again using pseudocode for clarity);

```
alter sequence seq set currval=pkey
```

For a little context, this table will be accessed by many virtual users as part of a performance test, they each need to be able to run a query that will get them a unique value (so vuser 1 gets 58b, vuser2 gets 24b, etc). The data cannot be ordered or filtered beforehand.

Comment: Why do you want a sequence if your intention is only to display a number that represents a sequence.Just use `row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY pkey ) as key`  or simply `rownum as key`  if you don't want any order.

Comment: It needs to be something that exists/persists between Oracle sessions and multiple users. If I understand rownum corectly, it only applies to that particular query at that particular time?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you actually want and the details you provided isn't helping me either. Your actual problem seems to be about some virtual users who will "*run a query that will get them a unique value*". What kind of users are they? database schemas? UI users? and how they will access the table? etc. There are better ways  like having another column to keep track of which are taken which are not etc. But, without any other info about the users and accessibility, it's hard to tell if it might work for you.

Comment: The users are virtual, basically small amounts of C code running in isolated threads or processes that are unaware of each other. The only thing they can do is run the same block of code that contains this query. There is already a 'used' column that we update after the select, but in the time between the select and the update another user/thread/process will run the same select statement and end up with the same record.

Comment: I'm not sure why that should be happening. You are probably either not committing the update or not excluding the rows that are already updated.

Comment: Things get very 'odd' when it comes to running performance tests. It's nothing to do with the update commit, the select query for the other user is happening even before that update has started. Ideally the select and update would happen simultaneously which isn't the same as the code I have at the moment. Having said that, I can see a method of doing a select and update at the same time which I'm looking into at the moment.

Comment: Without the code for update, I can't say much. Is it part of a language/ procedure which does that? May be you can use `FOR UPDATE` clause of the select to [LOCK the rows](http://www.oratable.com/how-to-lock-a-row-in-oracle/) to prevent other sessions from getting access to the row until committing.

Comment: For update doesn't work, because it's the same query I end up with row locks and nothing happening. Even when the lock is released the last thing I want is another user accessing that row. The update is simply 'update table set is_used=1 where VAL=<x>'.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to count the values that end in `b`?

```
select pkey, val,
       (case when val like '%b'
             then row_number() over (partition by (case when val like '%b' then 1 else 0 end) order by pkey
                                    )
        end) as b_seq
from table;
```

You can use this as a subquery if you want to find the row corresponding to a particular row of `b_seq`.

If you don't care about the other values, this is simpler to write with a `where` clause:

```
select pkey, val,
       row_number() over (order by pkey) as b_seq
from table
where val like '%b';
```

Comment: Hmm, that's not something I've seen before, I'll give it a go and report back. Thanks. I'm a bit confused how the row_number() works but I'm sure Google will bring something up for that particular element.

Comment: It doesn't look like that will work. The row_number() element brings back the values in order, but doesn't tell the user which row should be taken. If all the users ran that same query, they would all receive the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Gordon's answer I would do:

```
with
x as (
  select seq.nextval as s
),
y as (
  select pkey, val,
       row_number() over (order by pkey) as b_seq
  from table
  where val like '%b'
)
select y.* from y join x on y.b_seq = x.s
```

This way each request will increment the sequence and will return a different SINGLE value from the "b subset".